# select & textarea aren't save to database ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to save data that comes from the frontend to my database, some of it saves and the other just comes as 'null'. No errors, just null.
only the category is being saved. I don't really know why this is happening but my guess that the 'category' saves and the 'title' isn't is because of the multiple  options combined with the JS code.

Here is the HTML, the only thing that saves right now is the 'category'

```
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label asp-for="category" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<input asp-for="category" class="form-control" />*@
            <select asp-for="category" name="Category" id="Category" class="form-control">
                <option value="Road">Road problems</option>
                <option value="Urban">Urban problems</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="category" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="title" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<input asp-for="title" class="form-control" />*@
            <select asp-for="title" name="Road_problems" id="Road_Problems1" class="form-control">
                <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
                <option value="Disturptive_object">Disturptive object</option>
                <option value="Disturptive_parkings">Disturptive parking</option>
                <option value="Defective_indication">Defective indication</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>

            <select asp-for="title" name="Urban_problems" id="Urban_problems1" class="form-control">
                <option value="Neigborhood_problen">Neigborhood problen</option>
                <option value="Pollution">Pollution</option>
                <option value="Animals">Animals</option>
                <option value="Disturptive_object">Disturptive object</option>
                <option value="Tag">Tag</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>

            <select asp-for="title" name="Other" id="Other1" class="form-control">
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="title" class="text-danger"></span>

            <style>
                .form-group #Other1, #Urban_problems1 {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>

            <script>
                let category = document.getElementById("Category");
                let RP = document.getElementById("Road_Problems1");
                let UP = document.getElementById("Urban_problems1");
                let Other = document.getElementById("Other1");

                category.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    let cat = document.getElementById("Category").value;
                    show(cat);
                });

                function show(category) {
                    if (category == "Road") {
                        console.log('1');
                        RP.style = " display: inline"
                        UP.style = "display: none"
                        Other.style = " display: none"
                    } if (category == "Urban") {
                        console.log('2');
                        RP.style = " display: none"
                        UP.style = "display: inline"
                        Other.style = " display: none"
                    } if (category == "Other") {
                        console.log('3');
                        RP.style = " display: none"
                        UP.style = "display: none"
                        Other.style = " display: inline"
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="remarks" class="control-label"></label>
            @*<input asp-for="remarks" class="form-control" id="remarks" style="height: 140px; width: 100%"/>*@
            <textarea asp-for="remarks" class="form-control" name="paragraph_text" cols="50" rows="10" style="height: 140px; width: 100%"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="remarks" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

C#: Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ProjectHack.Models
{
    public class ReportModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Category")]
        public string category { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Problem description")]
        public string remarks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

C# ReportDAO - save the data

```
static readonly string connectionString = @"KEY";
    public static bool addReport(ReportModel report)
    {
        bool success = false;
        string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.Reports (category,title,description,statUrgence,cordsLat,cordsLong) VALUES (@category,@title,@description,@statUrgence,@cordsLat,@cordsLong)";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

            command.Parameters.Add("@category", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 32).Value = report.category;
            command.Parameters.Add("@title", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 32).Value = report.title;
            command.Parameters.Add("@description", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 150).Value = report.remarks;
            command.Parameters.Add("@statUrgence", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 32).Value = report.statUrgence;
            command.Parameters.Add("@cordsLat", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value = 3.15;
            command.Parameters.Add("@cordsLong", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value = 7.1;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                success = true;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return success;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a break when you are creating the SqlCommand and seeing if you're storing the data that you think you are?

Comment: I tried debugging, but it takes everything but does not store some of it.

Comment: You are storing it in a try/catch block - no errors in the console?

Comment: Tried try/catch and there wasn't any errors

Comment: And your bool flag is set to true so you know the code executes?

Comment: that code looks ok, but is the object filled out ok and does it have values before you try the insert??

Comment: Tell you what, I checked everything. 
When I debugged I saw that in the ReportDAO the information doesn't get there.
I looked at the input that the function 'addReport' the 'ReportModel report' the title and remarks are just Null.

Comment: Also, When I replace the <textarea> with a regular <input> it works just fine...

Comment: Nvm guys, problem fixed. the problem was the "Name"